# Django GROUP_BY through .annotate()

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have table `invoices` with field `customer_id` and some others fields. I need select count of purchases, taken by each user. In SQL it's should looks like this:

```
SELECT username, COUNT('customer_id') FROM `invoices`
LEFT JOIN `auth_user` ON `auth_user`.id =  `invoices`.customer_id
GROUP BY `customer_id`, username
```

In Django i try:

```
Invoice.objects.annotate(buy_count=Count('customer')).all()
```

But this code groups by `invoices.id` instead of `invoices.customer_id` and returns wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should turn it around, something like:

```
Customer.objects.annotate(buy_count=Count('invoice')).all()
```

There you'd get a list of Customer with their count of invoice.